# How to make discord.py bot execute a command of it's own?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a support system and because the bot stops listening to everything once I restart the bot, I want to send the support message again.

I tried making the bot say the support command, but it doesn't really work!

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
        channel = bot.get_channel(999949771735306282)
        await channel.send("sec>support-info")
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

Comment: You could look into something like [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks) or [events, in particular on_ready](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_ready#event-reference) but I think your problem could probably be solved better with persistent views? Here is an example from the official GitHub: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a command from inside another command or an event, you can use the following:

```py
command = bot.get_command('foo')
await command(ctx, arg:str="This is what you want to pass through an argument", second_arg="This is another argument, if you don't have any arguments in your command, you don't need these")
```

Remember to replace foo with your command name and if you have any arguments you can pass them in like I have demonstrated with arg and second_arg. If you don't have any arguments, you can remove those.

And here is the documentation of [get_command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20get_command#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_command).